# Sharepoint 2010 - make Title, Description and Keyword fields as required fields in Picture Library using server-object-model

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepointfoundation2010, sharepoint-object-model

I'm creating a Sharepoint feature, this feature has an event receiver associated to it. In the event receiver, I'm creating a Document Library and Picture Library using server-side object model. I'm also adding new custom columns (around 80) to these newly created document and picture library. Now I want to modify the properties of the Description, Keywords and Title fields that are by default created along with the picture library. I want to make these fields as Required fields. How do I do this? I tried to set SPList.AllowContentTypes = true and try to change the attributes of these fields, but it doesn't work (neither gives an error nor makes these required fields). I also tried to access the content types and try to change the attributes using SPContentType.FieldsLinks["Column_name"].Required and SPContentType.Fields["Column_name"].Required but it gives me an error. Does anyone have any other suggestions?

Comment: You need to set these fields as required for the **list**. So try to get the SPField from the list and set `SPField.Required` to `true`

Comment: no luck, these are not the fields that I created. they come with the Picture Library definition. I tried different ways to get references to SPField, but nothing worked so far...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the answer....

```
SPContentType ct = mypiclib.ContentTypes["Picture"];
SPFieldLinks titleLink = ct.FieldLinks["Title"];
SPFieldLinks descLink = ct.FieldLinks["comments"]; //internal name of Description
SPFieldLinks keywords = ct.FieldLinks["keywords"];
titlelink.Required = true;
descLink.Required = true;
keywords.Required = true;
ct.Update();
```

Answer (score 0):

can you tell us the error you got when trying to use the fieldlinks? Because this should work... I have done it like this:

```
SPContentType ct = web.Lists["*ListName*"].ContentTypes["*ContentTypeName*"];
SPFieldLinkCollection flinks = ct.FieldLinks;
flinks["*ColumnName*"].Required = true;
ct.update();
```

Comment: tried, it complains that Description field is not available in picture library... It actually exist, not sure how to handle Description field.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
SPWeb yourWeb =  ... //assign your web
SPList yourPictureLibrary = ... //assign your picture library

web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
yourPictureLibrary.Fields[SPBuiltInFieldId.Title].Required = true;
yourPictureLibrary.Fields[SPBuiltInFieldId.Description].Required = true;
yourPictureLibrary.Fields[SPBuiltInFieldId.Keywords].Required = true;
yourPictureLibrary.Update();
```

Comment: That gets those library fields required on the list instance but not on the content-type! I misread your question!

Answer (score 0):

[SPAllowContentTypes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.allowcontenttypes.asp) isn't settable. You might try setting [ContentTypesEnabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.contenttypesenabled.aspx) instead.

I don't have a 2010 box to test against, but if [SPAllowContentTypes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.allowcontenttypes.aspx) returns false I think you're looking at modifying the definition of your picture library in the 14 hive (TEMPLATE\FEATURES\PictureLibrary\PicLib) to get what you're after. Tread lightly there.